# Getting `[js] ';' expected` When added Constructor to Drawer Page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation module, Why I Got This Error: `[js] ';' expected` When added Constructor to My MyPhotosHomeScreen Page in DrawerNavigator?
I want to Read Data from js file and I want to add `dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),` and need to add a Constructor.

**MyPhotosHomeScreen Page:**

```
const MyNavScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <View>
    <View style={styles.containerNavbar}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}>
        <Icon name="bars" size={30} color="#fff" />
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text style={styles.navbarTitle}>Photos</Text>
    </View>

    <ScrollView>
      <View><Text>photo</Text></View>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} title="Go back" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
      style={styles.listContainer}
      renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    />
  </View>
);

const MyPhotosHomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <MyNavScreen navigation={navigation} />
);
MyPhotosHomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Photos',
  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <MaterialIcons
      name="photo"
      size={24}
      style={{ color: tintColor }}
    />
  ),
};
export default MyPhotosHomeScreen;
```

**And I want to add This constructor:**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 })
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
  }
}
```

**Bot I Got ThisError:**
[image: Photo]
And I opened an Issue in This Github page:(https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2218)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `constructor` needs to be inside a class...